# The constructor `Rectangle' should have 2 arguments, but has been given none

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

I have this code

```
type Point = (Int, Int)

data Points 
    = Rectangle Point Point
    | Union Points Points
    | Difference Points Points

inMax :: Int -> Int -> Int
inMax a b
    | a < b     = b
    | otherwise = a

inMin :: Int -> Int -> Int
inMin a b
    | a < b     = a
    | otherwise = b

inPoints :: Point -> Points -> Bool
inPoints (x, y) Rectangle (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = ((inMin x1 x2) <= x && x <= (inMax x1 x2)) && ((inMin y1 y2) <= y && y <= (inMax y1 y2))
```

I want to know if a point is in Rectangle but i got the next error: The constructor `Rectangle' should have 2 arguments, but has been given none. Why? How I should fix it?

Comment: `inPoints (x, y) Rectangle (x1, y1) (x2, y2)` has four arguments: `(x, y)`, `Rectangle` (unapplied), `(x1, y1)`, and `(x2, y2)`. You need more parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to "unpack" the `Rectangle`, then you write `Rectange` between parenthesis:

```
inPoints :: Point -> Points -> Bool
inPoints (x, y) (Rectangle (x1, y1) (x2, y2)) = --- …
--              ↑        parenthesis        ↑
```

We thus perform pattern matching to obtain the points of the `Rectangle`. You can *not* use `Rectange` itself as a patern.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `inPoints (x, y) Rectangle (x1, y1) (x2, y2)`, no matter if it appears in a pattern left of the `=`, or right of it, parses as

```
     (((inPoints (x,y))
                 Rectangle)
                 (x1,y1))
                 (x2,y2)
```

i.e. `Rectangle` is passed as an argument all by itself, and then `(x1,x2)` and `(x2,y2)` are passed as additional, separate arguments.

That's not completely absurd: in an expression, `Rectange` is just a function `Point -> Point -> Points`, and functions can be passed as function arguments just like any other values. For example you could define something like

```
unionBuilt :: (Point -> Point -> Points) -> [Point] -> Points
unionBuilt f (x₀:x₁:xs) = Union (f x₀ x₁) (unionBuilt xs)
unionBuilt f ... = ...
```

and that could then legitimately be called like

```
    unionBuilt Rectangle [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

But in a *pattern match*, all constructors must be fully applied, i.e. if you pattern match on `Rectangle` then it must always come with two patterns for the containing points (even if you're not interested in them; then you need to use a blank pattern). This generally requires wrapping it in parentheses

So what you want is

```
inPoints (x,y) (Rectangle (x₁,y₁) (x₂,y₂)) = ...
```

Like most parentheses in Haskell expressions, these are only needed if the precedence rules don't already establish this way of parsing. In particular, if you had defined your function as an *infix operator*, then you would have been fine, and don't actually need any parentheses at all (except for the tuples):

```
(∈) :: Point -> Points -> Bool
(x, y) ∈ Rectangle (x₁, y₁) (x₂, y₂)
  = inMin x₁ x₂ <= x && x <= inMax x₁ x₂
  && inMin y₁ y₂ <= y && y <= inMax y₁ y₂
```

This is because prefix function application, including constructors like `Rectangle`, always binds more tightly than infix operator application.